How to achieve access provisioning in Jenkins via python script?
I am the admin of Jenkins. I am planning to automate "Jenkins access provisioning task". currently we are using  matrix based authentication for providing access. But there are 500+ user are there, so when i try to load the "matrix access provisioning page" it is getting too slow, and then its getting difficult to search in the matrix box like which project & which uses because of the too slowness.
So I am planning to automate that via python. I checked couple of the Jenkins API docs, But no-luck there is no API for access provisioning alone, for running build, view job and all we have API. only for access provisioning we don't have i guess. So Folks kindly help on this how can i achieve this via python script so that i can automate.
this is how it looks like in matrix authentication (image for 500+ users, it looks very clumsy & difficult to locate the user name matrix cell)


https://www.jenkins.io/projects/jcasc/

At this point (500+ users), I would consider using LDAP or something and role-based access control that is configured via JCasC as suggested above.

What would that python script do? Automatic user sync between some json or yaml file and Jenkins? And how would you maintain that json or yaml file? In a text editor? That gives you a slightly snappier interface, but doesn't really solve your problem. If you have 500 users you probably need a directory to manage them. And then the real question is how to integrate your directory with Jenkins.

@AlexanderPletnev  Sorry sir, if my question doesn't provide the full context. Actually i want a python script or idea to use which API,  for automating the "access provisioning in jenkins". LDAP are already configured, when i try to give access via "matrix authication" for respective project, it is taking time consuming Since i need to search  in the matrix .

@AlexanderPletnev Main job that i need is that, when i give "user-id" to a python script it should check in the matrix authentication wether user is already exist are not. If exist,  that code just need to provide access for respective view/edit permission.
if user dosent exist it need to add & provide the same permission

You can't manage the users and their access with Python over the Jenkins API (and generally, such attempts wouldn't be a good idea from the security perspective anyway).
Jenkins Configuration as Code plugin provides you with such an option instead. You don't have to fully migrate your configuration to it immediately - its parts can be defined step by step.
At your scale it makes sense to use external authentication, but JCasC works even for local users.
You might want to look to the examples - the Global Matrix Auth one is the same configuration you're showing on your screenshot, by the way:

Embedded User Database
Global Matrix Auth

For external authentication:

LDAP
Active Directory
Google Login
GitHub OAuth


Sorry sir, if my question doesn't provide the full context. Actually i want a python script or idea to use which API, for automating the "access provisioning in jenkins". LDAP are already configured, when i try to give access via "matrix authication" for respective project, it is taking time consuming Since i need to search in the matrix

Main job that i need is that, when i give "user-id" to a python script it should check in the matrix authentication wether user is already exist are not. If exist,  that code just need to provide access for respective view/edit permission.
if user dosent exist it need to add & provide the same permission

There are no APIs for this. With JCasC, all you need to do is to create some mappings that show which access has each LDAP group and apply it. You don't need to create the users for that, the user will be taken automatically from the LDAP server upon logging in.
